# Interraction between PHP and Javascript

Tags: javascript, php

```
if((<?php ( $_GET[category] != ""); ?>){


  if (checkCookie != "") {
    $('#nav > li > a:eq('+checkCookie+')').addClass('active has-sub open').next().show();
}
```

Why the PHP part of this code isn't working?

Comment: What's not working? What does it look like after the page has been requested by the browser?

Comment: <script>



$(document).ready(function () {
 
 
  var checkCookie = $.cookie("nav-item");
  
 
  
  if (checkCookie != "") {
 $('#nav > li > a:eq('+checkCookie+')').addClass('active has-sub open').next().show();
  }
  
  $('#nav > li > a').click(function(){
      var navIndex = $('#nav > li > a').index(this);
   $.cookie("nav-item", navIndex);
  
 
  });
});
</script>

Comment: this is function, I need it with the get

Comment: You need to narrow the problem down. Look at the JavaScript source code that the PHP is outputting. Is it what you expect?

Answer (score 3):

You have to echo- out the php variable to javascript operator

```
   if((<?php echo ( $_GET[category] != "")? true : false; ?>){
      if (checkCookie != "") {
      $('#nav > li > a:eq('+checkCookie+')').addClass('active has-sub open').next().show();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set a variable to check, should you execute or not.

```
    var execute = false;
    <?php
        if (!empty($_GET["category"])) {
            echo 'execute = true;';
        }
    ?>
    if (execute){
        //Do what you want
    }
```

NOTE:

- Add quotes around `category` in the get
- You have a missing `}` sign to close your condition.
- You have an unnecessary `(` at the start of your first condition.

Answer (score 0):

if(document.URL!=''){
      if (checkCookie != "") {
      $('#nav > li > a:eq('+checkCookie+')').addClass('active has-sub open').next().show();
    }